# Calculating the m.g.f. of a Linear Function

Tags: linear, moments, moment-generating-function

I'm having trouble finding out how to determine the mgf of a linear transformation.

The problem I have gives me an mgf in the form of $\exp(t^2+ct)$, where $c$ is a constant that I'm not mentioning. The range is from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$. The question wants me to find the mgf of a linear transformation of $Z = aX + bY + d$ also.

The textbook has an example of calculating the mgf for the linear transformation, however I'm not able to understand the process. I'm rather new to mgf's, and am in need of some help in determining how to understand the process of finding a solution.

Comment: Can you explain what you want more clearly? What are your random variables? $X$, $Y$, and $Z$? Do you have the MGF of $X$? What about $Y$? And do you want to compute the MGF of $Z$?

Comment: I am guessing X, Y follow the given mgf, and you want to calculate the mgf for Z?

Comment: Well, it says something like Z = 2X + 3Y - 5. There is also a given mgf with m(t) = e^(something) from -infinity to infinity. There are random variables X and Y which are iid.

Answer (score 1):

It might not be an answer to your question but: 
$MGF =\psi_X(t)=E(e^{tx})$ so for your RV it will be: 
$\psi_Z(t)=E(e^{tZ})$

$=E(e^{t(aX+bY+d)})$ 
$=E(e^{taX} \cdot e^{tbY} \cdot e^{td})$ 
$=e^{td}\cdot E(e^{taX} \cdot e^{tbY})$  
$= e^{td}\cdot E(e^{taX}) \cdot E(e^{tbY})$

That is: $e^{td} \cdot \psi_X(ta) \cdot \psi_Y(tb)$

Assuming $X,Y$ are iid